# querying from cached data, simple linq statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of cached data

```
private static List<City> CachedCities
{
   get {  ... }
}
```

Now from that cached list I want to extract following using linq

```
private someOtherMethod()
{       
   foreach (var item in someData) {
    string cityName = from c in CachedCities where c.Id == item.Address.CityId select c.Name;
    ...
   }
}
```

I'm getting error on linq statement

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>
> `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` to `'string'`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

p.s. both c.Id and Address.CityId are strings.

Comment: Well presumably `city.Name` is declared as `IEnumerable<char>`. It's hard to say without a complete example. (Why are you declaring `cityName` outside your loop, by the way? And I assume you're actually doing some useful work in the loop?)

Comment: now cityName is declared as it should (left by outside of the linq statement by mistake). c.Name is string. Problem remains. I'm iterate trough someData to generate list of viewmodels to use it further. I'm getting error on select keyword in linq statement.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, because you are trying to assign an IEnumerable<string> to a string in your example. Can you provide a part of the actual (compiling) code?

Comment: @FredKleuver this is actual code. It doesnt compile. Question is how to make it compile. Where is error?

Comment: Well you're selecting a sequence of strings (a sequence of city names), not a single name. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this lambda query syntax

```
string cityName = CachedCities.Where(x => x.Id == item.Address.CityId)
                    .Select(a => a.Name)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a compilation error. The type you are assigning to cityName is IEnumerable and you are declaring it as a string.

Try the following:

```
string cityName = CachedCities.Where(c => c.Id == item.Address.CityId).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```